# TLP 1.4: Battery charge settings and performance question

Tags: ubuntu, battery

I've been reading about a good practice to install [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/index.html) to avoid battery being constantly overcharged.

I therefore installed the daemon on my Huaweii X Mate Pro. The battery is recognised as far as I can tell.

I set the thresholds as 30% 80%, which according to the doc signal to charge when below 30% and stop when it's 80.

I left the laptop yesterday night in charge and it was at 40%, and this morning the maximum status is 79/80 as expected, so the service evidently works.

My question is, if the battery will be never charged till the max (again another piece of advice I read around), isn't there a risk to have ions working inefficiently over time?
I guess that from time to time a full charge is required?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I appreciate I'm answering myself, but finally I was able to locate the right [explanation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html?highlight=full%20charge#how-to-choose-good-battery-charge-thresholds) on the software site. The explanation was a bit buried IMHO.

Quoting from the site:

> ...having a battery hold a lot of power will decrease its capacity
> over the years. To alleviate this problem, the start/stop charge
> thresholds can be adjusted – at the cost of a more or less reduced
> battery runtime.

So the right answer is to manipulate the thresholds according to the needs.

> If the laptop is plugged most of the time and rarely unplugged,
> maximizing battery lifetime at the cost of a greatly reduced runtime
> may be acceptable, with values like starting charge at 40% and
> stopping at 50%.
>
> On the contrary, if you use it unplugged most of the time, starting
> charge at 85% and stopping at 90% would allow for a much longer
> runtime and still give a lifespan benefit over the factory settings.

This translates in my opinion in having a maximum runtime setting in the configuration file (e.g. 70 90) and temporarily change the settings when you know that you are plugged in at lower level (e.g. 40 50). Settings can be changed temporarily with a `sudo tlp setcharge 40 50`.

Because TLP pass the values straight to the firmware, I guess there is not a need to restart anything. Checking if the new values have been taken also with a `sudo tlp-stat b` will confirm the changes.

Hopefully I took this correctly. I will confirm if not after having some trials.

Comment: [Self-answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) a question is fine (even if you get other answers - the community will vote to assess them).